# JBoss/Torquebox - How to set to listen to port 80

Tags: port, ubuntu-11.04, jboss

I am now trying to deploy my Rails application to Torquebox 2.0.3 on Ubuntu Server 11.04. Now it's correctly deployed , I could visit the application on port 8080. but I could not configure the server to listen to port 80.

I tried to set the port to listen in `$TORQUEBOX_HOME/jboss/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` :

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">

    ....

    <socket-binding name="http" port="80"/>

    ....
</socket-binding-group>
```

After that when I start Torquebox by calling `torquebox run`, and I get the following error:

```
15:47:07,804 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) Error initializing endpoint: java.net.BindException: Permission denied /127.0.0.1:80
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:190) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]

    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControlle

rImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Thread

PoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
```

But I find no process is holding port 80:

```
$ sudo lsof -i :80
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
$
```

How could I solve this problem and configure jboss server to listen to port 80?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lower numbered ports - lower than 1024 tend to be restricted to root users - the best/simplest way to get around this is to forward port 80 to 8080 internally at iptables or at the network's firewall, rather than at the application level.